# MT Software Suite for Linux (beta) problem

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
make
/bin/bash linklibdir.sh
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -I. -Ixsens -Iinclude  -c myxda.cpp -o myxda.cpp.o
myxda.cpp: In member function ‘void MyXda::openPorts()’:
myxda.cpp:56:55: error: converting to ‘const XsString’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘XsString::XsString(XsSize, const char*)’
include/xsens/xscontrol.h:129:14: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘bool XsControl::openPort(const XsString&, XsBaudRate, uint32_t)’
make: *** [myxda.cpp.o] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115866/mt-software-suite-for-linux-(beta)-problem/) by [lukeLAU](https://answers.ros.org/users/10596/lukelau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a fix for the error by changing `xsControl()->openPort(i->portNumber(), i->baudrate());` to `xsControl()->openPort(*i);` on Line 56 of myxda.cpp

I didn't get the error for MT SDK though, I got the error when I was compiling [receive_xsens](http://wiki.ros.org/receive_xsens) package.

---

Originally posted by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) with karma: 281 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0